# Setting Parameter Value of a Dynamically Added Crystal Report Sub-Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I'm working on a report were I dynamically add sub-reports to a main report like this:

```
   ReportDocument myReport = (...);

   for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
       String subreportname = (...);
       DataTable dt = (...);
       CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.Section sec = new CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportDefModel.Section();
       sec.Kind = CrAreaSectionKindEnum.crAreaSectionKindDetail;
       sec.Name = String.Format("DynamicSection{0}", i);
       sec.Width = crFinalGroup.ReportClientDocument.ReportDefController.ReportDefinition.PageHeaderArea.Sections[0].Width;

       myReport.ReportClientDocument.ReportDefController.ReportSectionController.Add(sec, myReport.ReportClientDocument.ReportDefController.ReportDefinition.DetailArea, i);
       myReport.ReportClientDocument.SubreportController.ImportSubreport(subreportname, "Some\Path\SubReport.rpt"), sec);
       myReport.Subreports[subreportname].SetDataSource(dt);
    }

    // set export options such as format and destination
    // ...

    myReport.Export();
    myReport.Close();
    myReport.Dispose();
```

Which works fine.

Now I need to add a parameter value to the sub-report `"Some\Path\SubReport.rpt"`. So I open up that report, create and configure a parameter value as usual. However, when I try to set a value for that newly creater parameter, I get an error:

(assuming the parameter name is `"pvalue"`)

```
myReport.SubReports[subreportname].SetParameterValue("pvalue", 0);
```

Throws a `"Not supported within subreports"` error

```
myReport.SetParameterValue("pvalue", 0, subreportname);
```

Works, but when exporting the `myReport` report, it throws a `"Missing parameter values"`

I've also tried creating the parameter in the main report (`myReport`), and setting it for both the main and sub-report:

```
 myReport.SetParameterValue("pvalue", 0);
 myReport.SetParameterValue("pvalue", 0, subreportname);
```

But I still get `"Missing parameter values"` when exporting the main report

Comment: R u using web application or windows applicatiojn?